# jQuery : Textbox empty or not

Tags: jquery

I have several textbox on a page, imagine 10, 4 of these 10 have the class "myClass". I'd like to know if ALL these textbox with class "myClass" have length = 0, in one line command

Possible?

Thanks,

**Update1**

```
function MyValidation() {
    var res = true;
    if (!$("input:text.MyClass[value!='']").length) {
        alert("testing");
        res = false;
    }
    return res;
}
```

When you this code, I receive a "true" all the time never "false" and never "testing". I tried the code of every answer.

Comment: Class names are case-sensitive. You should write `.myClass` instead of `.MyClass`.

Comment: I checked again and the case is ok

Comment: that's strange, it works for me in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FT3TZ/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should suffice

```
if ( $('.myClass').filter(function(){
                             return $(this).val() != '';
                           }).length == 0
   )
 {
  /* code to run when all are empty */

 }
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/QasRK/

---

To accommodate for white-space in the string change

```
return $(this).val() != '';
```

to

```
return $(this).val().replace(/\s/g,'') != '';
```

This strips the text of white-space before comparing it to `''`

Comment: Possible to add a Trim() ? space space space in the textbox must be considered as empty

Comment: @Kris, class names are case sensitive. if you use `myClass` in the html you should use the same in javascript and not `MyClass`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
if (!$(input.myClass).is(function() { return this.value.length > 0; }))
```

Answer (score 1):

That can also be done with the appropriate [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/):

```
if (!$("input:text.myClass[value!='']").length) {
    // All the .myClass text boxes are empty.
}
```

Comment: Not without using `not()`, `is()` or `filter()`, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to values:

```
var any = $("input:text.myClass").map(function() {
    var value = $.trim($(this).val());
    if (value != "") return value;
}).length > 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/e6yEd/

---

If you don't:

```
var any = $("input:text.myClass").filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).val()) != "";
}).length > 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/e6yEd/5/